# TreeView: How to determine if node is in edit mode?

Tags: delphi, treeview, delphi-2010

Is there a way to tell if a treeview node is currently in edit mode?

I'm using the KeyUp event to determine if the delete key was hit - I only want to fire off my 'do you really want to delete this' code if the user is NOT editing.

This project is using Delphi 2010.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can ask the [`TTreeView.IsEditing`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TCustomTreeView.IsEditing) property. From the reference:

> Indicates whether a node is currently being edited by the user.
>   **IsEditing** returns true if any node label in the tree view is being
>   edited.